# For referencing, how to get ex. 59,192–199. instead of 59:192–199. with apalike?

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

For referencing, how to get 59,192–199. instead of 59:192–199. with `\bibliography{apalike}` in overleaf?

Comment: Are you talking about the volume and page numbers one might see in the bibliography entry for an `@article` or about something else entirely. You can make your question much clearer by providing a short example document (along with a relevant `.bib` entry) that reproduces the status quo (a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). If I understand correctly, a solution here has to involve modifying the `.bst` file, which is always a bit tricky.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I will assume that you meant to write `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` rather than `\bibliography{apalike}`.

Second, I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `apalike.bst` in your TeX distribution. (If you're on Overleaf, locate the file https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/base/apalike.bst.) Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `apalike-comma.bst`. (Do *not* directly edit an original file in the TeX distribution.)
- Open the file `apalike-comma.bst` in a text editor. It has to be an ascii editor, not a word processor.
- Inside the file `apalike-comma.bst`, find the function called `format.vol.num.pages`. (In my copy of the file, this function starts on line 392.)
- Inside the function `format.vol.num.pages`, find the following line:

  ```
      { ":" * pages n.dashify * }
  ```

  Change it to

  ```
      { "," * pages n.dashify * }
  ```

  I will let you guess what the effect of this change is.
- Save the file `apalike-comma.bst` either in the directory (or overleaf folder) where your main tex file is loaded or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter method, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- In you main tex file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` to `\bibliographystyle{apalike-comma}`. Then rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Unfortunatly i don't seem to be able to open the apalike.bst file on the link you showed me. I reworked another version i found online that is a .bst.txt file but i don't know how to convert this.

Comment: @MatijsVandeVyver - Sorry for the broken url string. I believe I fixed it.

Comment: The apalike.bst in the link is also a .bst.txt file, do i need to convert it back to .bst somehow? Because I tried it with the .bst.txt in overleaf  but that doesn't seem to work. Sorry for my ignorance about all this, i'm quite new to this.

Comment: @MatijsVandeVyver - Definitely find a way to change the filename extension from `.bst.txt` to `.bst`. (I have no idea which editor would insist on affixing `.txt`. I suspect it's an editor that's been programmed do affix `.txt` automatically to any extension, such as `.bst`, it doesn't know about by default.)